# I'm getting this error in Codewars but it works fine in PyCharm?

Tags: python

Here's the question I'm working on!

Split Strings

Complete the solution so that it splits the string into pairs of two characters. If the string contains an odd number of characters then it should replace the missing second character of the final pair with an underscore ('_').

```
def solution(s):
    answer = []
    a = 0
    if (len(s) % 2) != 0:
        a = s + "_"
    for i in range(len(a) // 2):
        answer.append(a[2 * i:2 * i + 2])
    return answer

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 13, in <module>
    test.assert_equals(solution(inp), exp)
  File "/home/codewarrior/solution.py", line 6, in solution
    for i in range(len(a) // 2):
TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()
```

Comment: What do you think happens if `len(s) % 2 == 0`?

Comment: Omg, I'm dumb, sorry I'm new to this!

Answer (score 3):

The issue is you are initializing a as an integer `a=0`

If s is even, the line `a = s + "_"` is not executed. So `a` remains an integer in that case.

Which is why `(len(a) // 2)` gives an error. `len` does not work with integers, only with strings.

To fix the issue, initialize `a=s`